# Reflect all changes in the ObjectContext without persisting to the database

Tags: c#, linq, oracle, entity-framework, objectcontext

Because `ObjectContext.SaveChanges()` occurs within a transaction I decided it would be best for my app to first perform all queries / updates on the `ObjectContext` before calling `SaveChanges()` once to write the data to the database.

However doing this means that if I create an object and subsquently query the `ObjectContext` it denies it exists (presumbily because the database has yet to be updated).  I assumed I could get around this with some of the [SaveOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd395500.aspx) but it doesn't look like I can.

I basically want the `ObjectContext` to act like a proxy that I can modify as I wish to commit all in once go. Is there a way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't save changes your new objects don't exist in the database and no query executed against database (= no Linq to entities query) will return them. To get objects added to context but not saved yet you must query `ObjectStateManager`:

```
var data = context.ObjectStateManager
                  .GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added)
                  .Where(e => !e.IsRelationship)
                  .Select(e => e.Entity)
                  .OfType<YourEntityType>();
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had to do something along these lines in a similar situation:

Given a list of keys and values, where some of the keys are new, and wanting to update/insert keys and values in a single `SaveChanges`, I first pull down all the existing keys, then maintain a **separate** collection of `keysIncludingNewOnes`, which starts off containing just the existing keys, but also gets any newly-created keys added to it.

Then when I'm looking for a key object to associate with a value, I look in `keysIncludingNewOnes`, rather than querying the context, since (as you have found) the context doesn't know about the new keys until a `SaveChanges`.

It should be relatively easy for you to remember about your 'pending addition' objects; if it's not you may have a too-long-lived context, which in general creates its own problems.